# WPF application throws ambiguous function or property

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I am having trouble on my WPF application . My sample class file

```
public void InitializeComponent() {
            if (_contentLoaded) {
                return;
            }
            _contentLoaded = true;
            System.Uri resourceLocater = new System.Uri("/TRSS;component/controls/tab.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);

            #line 1 "..\..\..\controls\tab.xaml"
            System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, resourceLocater);


        }
```

The Compiler generates g.cs & g.i.cs with the same function above . So it shows ambiguity in g.cs file .

What i have tried is

Deleted or Commented g.cs file . But No Luck on every time build the file auto generates.
Commented the ambiguity function in .cs file . Throws unable to find the function `InitializeComponent();`

I am stuck . may i know anyone ever before faced this issue .

Comment: g.cs and g.i.cs gets autogenerated whenever you build your project.  Try to clean and rebuild your solution. If doesn't succeed post the code of xaml and code behind here because most likely issue is in your XAML and code behind code.

Comment: You better avoid editing or even looking inside of auto-generated cs-files. Ambiguity (whatever that means, you didn't post screenshot or exception) is more likely caused by your code.

Answer (score 1):

I have just had this issue and have done most of the things listed above. I think in my case the problem started when I renamed a UserControl by hand and missed some references. Every attempt to build after that gave me the issue described in the question. I have fixed this by Deleting the .xaml file (UserControl), this also automatically deletes the associated .xaml.cs file, compiling, and then adding a new control back into the project. I then copied the content of the old new one and all was well again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the namespace on the xaml match the xaml's code behind namespace.